# Take photo and store in custom album in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, camera

I want to take a photo and save them within a custom album on a iPad.
I tried a lot of things but ended always with wrong image orientation.

My current procedure is:

1. Take photo with Xamarin.Media and safe image somewhere in my app path
2. Create custom album if it's not existing
3. Load image from temporary path and save to the album
4. Add the image (asset) additionally to the custom album created in 2.

The workflow above is fully working except of saving the correct orientation. After loading an image with `library.AssetForUrl()` the containing orientation is every time up. Also after converting from `asset` -> `CGImage` -> `UImage (uiImage.Orientation)`.

In step 3 I tried to set the orientation the the appropriate one with

```
var image = new UIImage(tempImage.CGImage, 1.0f, UIImageOrientation.MyOrientation)
```

and also with the save command

```
library.WriteImageToSavedPhotosAlbum(image.CGImage, myOrientation, SaveCompletionBlock)
```

But the orientation is still ignored. I checked this by opening the Album application as well as loading the file in my self written gallery app.

I want to avoid the use of the `iOS` picker to take photos. This will produce a mess of code!

Or is there any third party library which allows to take photos and store them in a custom album? Which takes care of all the metadata information? It doesn't matter if it's written in `objective-c` or `c#`. I will create bindings for it. But it's awful to work with the camera and albums in `iOS`.

Comment: have a look at nicwises snipped. helped me a lot (transform the cgimage...) https://gist.github.com/nicwise/890460

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of hand-made `UIImagePickerController` alternatives. Some of them:

- https://github.com/w5mith/WSAssetPickerController
- https://github.com/chute/photo-picker-plus-ios
- https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController

Comment: Question was for Xamarin not native ios

Comment: Glad you're unfrozen. There is semi-auto binding generator (http://blog.xamarin.com/introducing-objective-sharpie/).